# Maximising $K_{s}$ in a $K_m$ free graph

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics

A graph $G$ on $n$ vertices does not contain a $K_{m}$ (complete subgraph with $m$ vertex). What is the maximum number of $K_{s}$ ($s<m$) in $G$, taken as a function of $s$, $n$, and $m$?

Comment: Assuming that you have a fixed number of vertices, I believe that this is an open problem.  You can consider an $s$-uniform hypergraph $\mathcal{H}$ on $n$ vertices and ask for the maximum number of $s$-hyperedges of $\mathcal{H}$ such that $\mathcal{H}$ is devoid of a subgraph isomorphic to the complete $s$-uniform hypergraph $K^{(s)}_m$ on $m$ vertices.  According to Page 9 of http://math.mit.edu/~cb_lee/18.318/lecture1.pdf, for $m=4$ and $s=3$,  this is is still an open problem, but the maximum number of $3$-hyperedges is conjectured to go like $$\frac{5}{9}\,\binom{n}{3}$$ for large $n$.

Comment: However, if I am not mistaken, then you can produce an $s$-uniform hypergraph $\mathcal{H}$ on $n$-vertices which is $K^{(s)}_m$-free and which has around $$\left(\frac{n}{m-1}\right)^s\,\binom{m-1}{s}\approx \frac{s!}{(m-1)^s}\,\binom{m-1}{s}\,\binom{n}{s}$$ $s$-hyperedges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I have found [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0602191) article which answers this problem in Theorem one and includes a proof in appendix A. hope you enjoy.